# How to set jackson timezone to system default?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, timezone

I want to set the `jackson` object mapper timezone always to system default. I could achieve this by overriding the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. But I'd rather want to make use of the existing `application.properties` called `spring.jackson.time-zone`.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer init() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        }
    };
}
```

But there is also a `spring.jackson.time-zone` application.properties. Would it also be possible to directly use this? The following does not work. But I even don't know if I'm using the `spel` expression correctly in app properties:

`spring.jackson.time-zone=#{T(java.util.TimeZone).getDefault()}`

Comment: You could write your own `PropertySource`.